# Refresh datagridview from another user control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Using C# and Winform.

I read a couple of similar questions but couldn't find any great answers that could interlock with my code. So, bear with me and thank you in advance for helping me.

I have a single form that contains multiple User Controls. Inside the first user control, you can insert, update and delete records from the database. In the second User Control, there is a datagridview that is populated with all records.

The problem I have is that whenever I insert, update or delete a record inside the first user control. It won't refresh inside the datagridview when I swap to the second user control.

Beneath is the **second** user control that populates the datagridview

```
private void populate()
    {
        database.OpenConnection();
        string query = "SELECT id, name, qoute, time, date from maintable";
        SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter(query, database.connection);
        SQLiteCommandBuilder builder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(sda);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);
        dtgNav.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        databas.CloseConnection();
    }

    private void Navigation_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populate();
        dtgNav.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        this.Refresh(); 
    }
```

Beneath is the code for adding a record to the datagridview in the **first** user control

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        database.OpenConnection();
        string query = "INSERT INTO maintable (`id`, `name`, `qoute`, `time`,`date`) VALUES (@Id, @Name, @Qoute, @Time, @Date)";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(query, database.connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", tbxID.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", tbxName.Text.Trim());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qoute", tbxQoute.Text.Trim());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", tbxTime.Text.Trim());
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dtpDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Added new event into the database.");
        database.CloseConnection();
        
        usercontrol2.Refresh();
        
    }
```

I would appreciate it if we found a way to refresh the datagridview when the button is clicked without changing the original code all too much.

Comment: The way I do this is to bind the DGV to a BindingSource (which is, in turn, bound to the DGV data, typically a `List<T>`). When I want to update the DGV, I call `ResetBindings` on the BindingSource

Answer (score 0):

You have a `public void Refresh` method in the second usercontrol, try modifying `this.Refresh();`, to say `populate();`. this should call your `private void populate` method that you called when loading which should reload the grid. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: `Refresh` merely causes the control to be repainted - has nothing at all to do with the data

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp The questioner has a `public void Refresh() {...}` method posted.  This answer is just suggesting to add the line `populate();` inside that method.